# Got Refused Entry to Thailand

Tags: thailand, denial-of-entry

My Uncle went to Thailand on Saturday 14th 2015 and when he arrived at Bangkok airport he got refused entry when he asked them why they said speak to your government in UK. he had to come back home.

Now we are all very confused on why this has happened...please can you give me some advice on who i need to speak to about this?

Comment: They must have given more of a reason, they would almost never just say 'no'.  Can you provide more details? What did they stamp in his passport? Was he on a tourist visa? British passport, I assume?

Answer (score 5):

A couple of possibilities based on your limited details.  1: There is something noted in his passport or a problem with his passport, 2: The UK has placed his name on a watch list, that is shared with other governments.

He should check with the nearest passport office to see if his passport has been canceled or blocked in any way or if there is a physical problem, like non readable swipe code or bad chip (if it has one).

If there is not an issue with the passport itself, then he might need to check with the government to seeif his name (or someone else with the same name) is on any watch lisr or wanted list.  Not familiar enough with the UK goverment to suggest a spe ific department.